# what is -z option in test command(linux)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In one of my lab tutorial there was a command to be checked.

```
test -z $LOGNAME || echo Logname is not defined
```

when I execute this command the output is "Logname is not defined". Man page for test says

```
> -z STRING
>               the length of STRING is zero
```

when I echo $LOGNAME it prints out my login name. So there is a value for $LOGNAME. In the first command above since the right part of the command is executed, it implies the left part has returned false. Why does it return false when $LOGNAME  has a value?

Comment: There is a big difference between "zero length" and "not defined".  `STRING=''` defines a string of length zero.  The `-z` option to test does not distinguish between undefined or zero length.

Comment: thanx for that info William

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
test -z $LOGNAME || echo Logname is not defined
```

is an [OR list](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), and can be translated as:

**DO** `echo Logname is not defined` **IF** `test -z $LOGNAME` **FAILS**

As you mention in your question, `test -z $LOGNAME` tests whether `$LOGNAME` is zero length ... and since it isn't, the test fails. Replacing `||` with `&&` as follows will give you the behaviour you want:

```
test -z $LOGNAME && echo Logname is not defined
```

**EDIT**: As per William Pursell's comment below, `test -n` (test for a non-zero-length string) and `||` might make more conceptual sense, but you need to quote `$LOGNAME` in this case (and in fact it's a good idea to get into the habit of quoting variables in general):

```
test -n "$LOGNAME" || echo Logname is not defined
```

Comment: thank you. I was unable to understand what the -z option does before. Now I understood.

Comment: So the shell would return 1 for failure and 0 for success. which is the opposite compared to other languages?if we think it that way. It is confusing since if the left part is evaluated to 1 the right part doesn't have to be executed

Comment: @DesirePRG Yes, an exit status of 0 indicates success - it's not a boolean value. Commands can return any exit status from 0 to 255, which is used to inform the user / other programs what kind of error happened (where "0" is "no error").

Comment: You must be careful with the quoting.  `test -n $foo` is a disaster waiting to happen because it will succeed if foo is undefined, but not if foo is of zero length.  `test -z $foo` works as expected (ie, it succeeds both when `foo` is undefined and when `foo` is of zero length), but it is a good idea to use `test -z "$foo"` and avoid the pathological case.  (`test -z $foo` succeeds when foo is undefined because the string `-z` is non-empty.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Good catch - I've added a little to the answer per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

test command looks for mentioned file in current folder, If you want check file from another location provide with full path and don't use -z option or use -s option . You can do as below:

> test /usr/bin/logname && echo $LOGNAME || echo Logname is not defined

or

> test -s /usr/bin/logname && echo $LOGNAME ||  echo Logname is not define

Comment: Suggest you read the question again ...

Comment: According to you if 'test -z $LOGNAME && echo Logname is not defined' is correct then it print the output of 'test -z $LOGNAME && echo $LOGNAME || echo Logname is not define' should correct output.
Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Nope - you don't understand how `test -z` works. Try it for yourself.